# Why can't I write this particular assignment in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, android-viewmodel

I'm using the MVI pattern in a project so I wrote both State and Event classes. For the Event part inside the viewModel I'm using a private property _event of type MutableLiveData, and exposing it to the Activity as a LiveData, this way:

```
private val _event = MutableLiveData<Event>()
val event: LiveData<Event>
    get() {
        return _event
    }
```

Everything worked well until I needed to use the SingleLiveEvent class (instead of its supertype MutableLiveData) found in this [sample code](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) from Google; the SingleLiveEvent class extends MutableLiveData which in turn extends LiveData.

So I thought that I could write something like this:

```
private val _event: LiveData<Event> = SingleLiveEvent()
val event: LiveData<Event>
    get() {
        return _event
    }
```

But i get this error in the editor:

Type mismatch.
Required: LiveData<ConfirmTransactionViewModel.Event>
Found: SingleLiveEvent<ConfirmTransactionViewModel.Event>

What am I missing? SingleLiveEvent is a subtype of LiveData and it has the same type parameter, so why won't this assignment work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you convert the Java code from the sample into Kotlin? If yes, please provide the code of `SingleLiveEvent` in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I would bet you auto-converted the `SingleLiveEvent<T>` Java code to Kotlin, and it declared it as a subclass of `MutableLiveData<T?>` instead of `MutableLiveData<T>`.

Comment: You're 100% right, thanks! (the code of SingleLiveEvent is substantially identical to the sample one)

I still don't get why adding nullability to the type parameter of SingleLiveEvent produces that particular error but now it works.

Comment: @hold94en well with the old declaration `SingleLiveEvent<Event>` was a `MutableLiveData<Event?>`, which is not a subtype of `MutableLiveData<Event>`. When you get a value from `MutableLiveData<Event>`, it is guaranteed that it is not null. However, you can get nulls from an instance of `MutableLiveData<Event?>`, so it cannot be a subtype of `MutableLiveData<Event>`.